# Convert video stream format

Tags: video

how can I convert H.265 video stream format to H.264 using python?
I do not know how to perform the convention
I have to perform it via gstreamer based on python on windows
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like that works as an example

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst

Gst.init(None)
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("filesrc location=test.m4v ! decodebin ! video/x-raw ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(
    Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
    Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS
)

if msg:
    t = msg.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, dbg = msg.parse_error()
        print("ERROR:", msg.src.get_name(), " ", err.message)
        if dbg:
            print("debugging info:", dbg)
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
    else:
        # this should not happen. we only asked for ERROR and EOS
        print("ERROR: Unexpected message received.")

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Best regards